# Azure Page Blob OpenRead does not fetch more than StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have a page blob containing effectively log data.  Everything works fine until the log fills up past 2 MB.

When Reading, I'm using the OpenReadAsync method to get a stream from which I read data out of.  Prior to calling OpenReadAsync, I set StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes to 2MB (2 * 1024 * 1024).

After opening the stream, I use the following method to read data out.

```
public IEnumerable<object> Read(Stream pageAlignedEventStream, long? maxBytes = null)
    {
        while (pageAlignedEventStream.Position < (maxBytes ?? pageAlignedEventStream.Length))
        {
            byte[] bytesToReadBuffer = new byte[LongZero.Length];
            pageAlignedEventStream.Read(bytesToReadBuffer, 0, LongZero.Length);
            long bytesToRead = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytesToReadBuffer, 0);

            if (bytesToRead == 0)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            if (bytesToRead < 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid size specification.  Stream may be corrupted.");
            }

            if (bytesToRead > Int32.MaxValue)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Payload size is too large.");
            }

            byte[] payload = new byte[bytesToRead];                
            int read = pageAlignedEventStream.Read(payload, 0, (int) bytesToRead);

            if (read != bytesToRead)
            {
                // when fails, read == 503, bytesToRead = 3575, position = 2MB (2*1024*14024)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Did not read expected number of bytes.");
            }

            yield return this.EventSerializer.DeserializeFromStream(new MemoryStream(payload, false));

            var paddedSpaceToSkip = PagesRequired(bytesToRead) * PageSizeBytes - bytesToRead - LongZero.Length;
            pageAlignedEventStream.Position += paddedSpaceToSkip;
        }

        yield break;
    }
```

As noted in the comments in the code, the failure happends when the position reaches the 2MB specified.  The read fails to pull additional bytes before returning and only reads 503 bytes instead of the expected 3575 bytes.

My expectation was that as I read past the buffer size, it would download more data.

I found a similar issue on [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/5075427-fix-bug-azure-blob-client-has-issues-when-reading), but linked issue indicates a non-power-of-2 buffersize but 2MB is definitely power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

I could fetch the all data (Size=3MB) that stored in a page blob even though I set [StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.streamminimumreadsizeinbytes.aspx) of CloudPageBlob to 2MB.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainername");

container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudPageBlob pageBlob = container.GetPageBlobReference("mypageblob");

pageBlob.StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes = 2 * 1024 * 1024;

Task<Stream> pageAlignedEventStream = pageBlob.OpenReadAsync();
```

> The read fails to pull additional bytes before returning and only reads 503 bytes instead of the expected 3575 bytes.

If that many bytes are not currently available and the end of the stream has been reached, the returned value could be less than the number of bytes requested. Please debug your code to trace the changes of variable of **paddedSpaceToSkip** and check whether your code logic is as expected.

Comment: the code is working correctly.  I wrote my own implementation of a stream that can read chunks from a blob and using that stream, everything is fine.  using the OpenReadAsync stream does not work for me.  I'm wondering if the yield is causing problems since i'm not reading all the bytes at once?

Comment: Also, since all the objects are the same size and they read fine it's not a problem with the read. it's only at the 2MB border.  that object exists across the boundary.  the read call returns less than expected bytes while there are many more bytes available after that 2MB buffer.

Comment: could you share us the code you are using to fetch pageAlignedEventStream?